# Avoid first load in adodc with a DataGrid component vb6

Tags: datagrid, vb6

i have an application that was made with Data components and DBGrid to show the results, but now we want to change this to access to a sql database using Datagrid and Adodc.

The problem here is that the from seems to load very slow compared when it had the Data component.

There is a form to avoid the load of the Adodc when the form is loaded, and do it later manually?

Comment: Well with some trial and error, i found that is not obligatory to select a datasource, and you can set the value later.

Comment: Have you tried leaving ConnectionString empty, and assigning it a value in code when you are "ready" to connect?